# git add -p file_name

Tags: git

при команде git add  -p file_name должен быть интерактивный режим с последовательным подтверждением каждого изменения, но в реальности получается что все изменения предлагаются сразу оптом а не последовательно - может нужно что то в настройках гита поправить? windows 10

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, file_name — это уже отслеживаемый git'ом файл (добавленный и закоммиченный ранее) или новый?

Comment: пробовал с отслеживаемым и новым файлом, результат одинаков - все изменения идут оптом

Comment: В отслеживаемых файлах добавление может происходить "оптом", если изменения слишком близко друг к другу, то есть между измененными меньше 11 неизмененных строк. Тогда git их считает одним блоком изменений (hunk). Чтоб добавлять построчно я предпочитаю `git-gui.exe`, который идёт в комплекте git for windows.

Comment: Спасибо Герман!